# Edit and examine existing filter views in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I inherited a monster sheet that is pretty much constantly used by multiple persons. It contains several filter views.

**Is there any way to find out what exactly each filter view does** without manually going to the filter view and then checking each column for conditions present? This sheet has over 50 columns, so doing this manually is a royal pita. Editing them is as well. The filter views include things like filtering by colors, filtering by meeting cell content conditions and possibly other things.

Comment: This might help [Guides to ask a \[google-sheets\] question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4935/88163)

Answer (score 1):

You can list filter views with the [Sheets API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). Paste the spreadsheet ID in the `spreadsheetId` field and click **Execute**. You can find the spreadsheet ID in the web browser address bar — it is the bit between `/d/` and `/edit`.

The response shows filter views in this format:

```
      "filterViews": [
        {
          "filterViewId": 336145647,
          "title": "Show all",
          "range": {
            "sheetId": 2048818001,
            "startRowIndex": 1,
            "endRowIndex": 200,
            "startColumnIndex": 3,
            "endColumnIndex": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "filterViewId": 1676824153,
          "title": "AJC",
          "range": {
            "sheetId": 2048818001,
            "startRowIndex": 1,
            "endRowIndex": 200,
            "startColumnIndex": 3,
            "endColumnIndex": 4
          },
          "criteria": {
            "3": {
              "hiddenValues": [
                "NDT",
                "",
                "ASG",
                "DED",
                "KDG",
                "LH",
                "WBV",
                "WGC"
              ]
            }
          },
          "filterSpecs": [
            {
              "columnIndex": 3,
              "filterCriteria": {
                "hiddenValues": [
                  "NDT",
                  "",
                  "ASG",
                  "DED",
                  "KDG",
                  "LH",
                  "WBV",
                  "WGC"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        ...
```

The response will include many other items as well. To get just the filter views programmatically, use the [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) method and set the fields URL parameter to `sheets/filterViews` as shown in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters#filter-views).